# Transfering Items to Another Account On PS4

Tags: ps4

Can you transfer items that you already bought on a PS4 account to another PS4 account? The accounts are in the same console, and I need to know how.

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot transfer digital purchases from one PSN account to another. However,if the PS4 is registered as the primary PS4 for the user that owns a game, the other user on that PS4 can play it under their account.